# I can not get The file from HTML to Php while trying to Upload

Tags: php, html, mysql

whenever i try to check if i got the file to upload or not i can not see the file. everytime it is printing out please select the file even after selecting the file.. can you guys please help me out.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="functionTest.php" name="myForm" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" >
            <input type="submit" name="submitBottom" value="upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**functionTest.php**

```
<?php

$serverName = 'mysql.metropolia.fi';
$username ='*******';
$password ='*******';
$db = '*******';

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$username,$password,$db)
or die("Error " . mysqli_connect_error());

$Image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
if (!isset($file)){
    echo"please select the file";
}else {
    echo $image = ($_FILES['Image']['name']);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <html>
<body>
<form action="functionTest.php" name="myForm" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" >
<inpu***t type="submit" name="submitBottom" value="upload">
</form>
</body>


</html>
<?php

$serverName = 'mysql.metropolia.fi';
$username ='*************';
$password ='***************';
$db = '*******';

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$username,$password,$db)
or die("Error " . mysqli_connect_error());

if (!$_FILES['image']['name']){
    echo"please select the file";
}else {
    echo $_FILES['Image']['name'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**functionTest.php**
You haven't extracted POST value.

```
$serverName = 'mysql.metropolia.fi';
$username ='*******';
$password ='*******';
$db = '*******';

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$username,$password,$db)
or die("Error " . mysqli_connect_error());

extract($_POST);

if (empty($_FILES['image']["name"]))
{
  echo "please select the file";
}
else
{
    echo $image = ($_FILES['image']['name']);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have made some mistakes by  taking different name of input and trying to get values from different name variables. try below code

```
  <html>
    <body>
    <form action="" name="myForm" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBottom" value="upload"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $serverName = 'mysql.metropolia.fi';
    $username ='*******';
    $password ='*******';
    $db = '*******';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$username,$password,$db)
    or die("Error " . mysqli_connect_error());

  if(isset($_POST)  && count($_POST)){
        $Image =$_FILES['image']['name'];
        if (!isset($Image)){
            echo"please select the file";
        }else {
            echo $image = ($_FILES['image']['name']);
        }


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: yes i fix that name variation and i tried your code as well still printing please select the file

Comment: above given already tested code work fine copy paste and try it